# How to empty a many to many field in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many, django-errors

I would like to empty all things within the following many to many field(`weekday_with_class`):

```
 all_existing_class.weekday_with_class = None
```

Here is the models.py:

```
   weekday_with_class = models.ManyToManyField('Weekday', blank=True, related_name='weekday_with_class')
```

However, if I execute the above code, I get this error:

```
Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use weekday_with_class.set() instead.
```

How is it possible to basically make my `weekday_with_class` empty for an instance? Thank you, and please leave a comment if you need any more information.

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
all_existing_class.weekday_with_class.clear()
```